Why is running ST_TRANSFORM() taking so long for a single point in Snowflake?
I have some geography points with a radius in meters. I want to convert the points into circles so that I can query if other points fall within those circles. But doing this seems to take forever.
This is what I have: Take a lat/lon point (all in the UK), convert to a meters based coordinate system, buffer 10 meters, convert back to a lat/lon point.
I killed the query after running for ~5 minutes, because it seemed like I must be doing something wrong. (This assumption that calculations should be quick is based on being able to do these calculations quickly on my laptop, so maybe I just don't understand the limitations of database resources)
select 
    st_makegeompoint(-0.144407, 51.489420) as pt
    , st_transform(
        st_buffer(
            st_transform(
                pt, 4326, 27700)
            , 10)
        , 27700, 4326) as circle

Other queries run fine, so it's not a broader database problem.
I have a functional workaround (pairwise distances), but I assume it's horribly inefficient vs. a spatial lookup via ST_CONTAINS

If you don't need the circles for anything else than a subsequent st_contains(), use st_dwithin() instead. It accepts (4326)geographies and a distance_in_meters, so you don't need to st_transform() back and forth to switch from degrees to meters, plus you avoid the quarter circle segmentation that comes with st_buffer(). If you choose to stick to st_contains(), make sure that's really what you want - it's more expensive than st_intersects() just to discard geoms that only touch the boundary without entering.

That might be an improvement over pairwise comparisons, I'll check it out. I don' think i have permissions to add search optimization to a column, but you helped get me here, which is very useful - https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/search-optimization/geospatial-queries
